# Mini-sized floating windows on a html page

Tags: javascript, html, css

How do I create a small mini floating window on my right of page?

I would like to create something like a "LIVE CHAT" floating window concept.

TQ

Comment: tried something so far?

Answer (score 1):

Use fixed position if you want it to scroll with the page, absolute position if not:

```
#chat
{
    width: 300px;
    height: 100%;

    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;

    background: red;
}
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rb43F/)